# grails log messages not displaying on STS 3.0 console

Tags: grails, logging, console, springsource

I am using Grails 2.1 bundled with the SpringSource's Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 3.0 and 
have been unsuccessful in getting log messages to display in the console window. I have
set the following in the config.groovy
 `log4j = {`
 `info 'grails.app.controller'`
 `}`

However when I use the following line in a controller it does not display in the console

`log.info " Hello World!"`

Any comments are tips would be welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because you haven't invoked the **`appender`** for the console.

You can do it like:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        console name: "stdout", threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO
    }
}
```

You can also specify custom patterns using the ***layout*** setting:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        console name: "stdout",
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%c{2} %m%n")
    }
}
```

Ref: [Grails Logging](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/single.html#logging)

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback, it appears that my problem was not adding an s to the end of controller. So my declaration should have been: info 'grails.app.controllers'

Comment: Yeah! makes sense.. I was already wondering the situation here. I haven't worked past 2.0 grails release so I thought this could have been a problem. Case closed ;)